# How to rewrite this function in D3 v3 into D3 v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, directed-graph

I got one question abut D3.js.
In v3 there was a function called

```
d3.layout.tree.links(nodes)
```

I just looked up at the D3 documentation, it says, that in v3

```
d3.layout.tree().links(nodes)
```

is available, but in v4 it is not listed anymore.
What this function does is:

> Given the specified array of nodes, such as those returned by nodes,
>   returns an array of objects representing the links from parent to
>   child for each node. Leaf nodes will not have any links. Each link is
>   an object with two attributes:
>
> ```
> source - the parent node (as described above).
> target - the child node.
> ```

Do you guys maybe know how to solve this problem using d3 v4? I want to use it to build a directed force chart in v4.

Thanks so much!

Comment: The approach has changed considerably...i would suggest you to go through this example https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/76d6fa0dff4af77544da9dd69aef9249 or https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

Comment: Hey guys, i just found the solution! You can use hierarchy.links: https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#node_links